# How do you reference a variable added to a ScriptScope from IronRuby?

Tags: c#, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

I'm trying to add a Variable to the scope and then access that variable from my ruby expression.

c#

```
ScriptRuntime runtime = IronRuby.Ruby.CreateRuntime();
var scope = runtime.ExecuteFile("C:\\codebase\\Test\\Test2\\Test2\\person2.rb");
scope.SetVariable("name", "Scott");
dynamic person = scope.Engine.Execute("p = Person.new(name)");
person.sayHi();
```

Ruby

```
class Person
   def initialize(name)
      @name = name.capitalize
   end
   def sayHi
      puts "Hello #{@name}!"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were pretty close. Just change the last two lines of your C# code to the next ones:

```
dynamic p = scope.Engine.Execute("Person.new(name)", scope);
p.sayHi();
```

In addition, though I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, you can use your class from C# in an easier fashion:

```
var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
var scope = engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\codebase\Test\Test2\Test2\person2.rb");

dynamic globalConstants = engine.Runtime.Globals;
dynamic person = globalConstants.Person.@new("shay");
person.sayHi();
```

Comment: I wrongly assumed that since you were calling Execute from the scope it would have everything necessary already in scope. The globalConstants stuff is cool too. That is a cleaner way to call into ruby.